# Obtaining off-road location on an android device

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am currently using the following code to get my location:

```
Location myPos = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(googleApiClient);
```

This seems to try and snap my location to a road (not always, but often), but this is **not** what I want at all. Is there a way to get the "last known/best location" but without snapping to roads?